# Traits: Interop between Scala and Java, accessing val from Java

Tags: java, scala, interop, traits

Assume this simple trait. A trait which exposes a **val x**. Since the initialization costs of **x** are very high I choose **val x =...** over **def x =...**

```
trait ScalaTrait {

  self =>

  val x: Int = SomeVeryExpensiveOperation.do()

}
```

Now how about a Java class implementing this trait. I'm of course obliged to implement **val x** using a public method in my Java class. But here is the catch: because the public method and my trait's **val x** share the same name I can't just delegate to the trait implementation:

```
class JavaClass imlements ScalaTrait {
    @Override
    public x() {
        /* I can't hand over this call to x() of the trait,
           since this would be a recursive call inside the Java class itself*/
        return x(); <-- so, this no can do!
    }

}
```

My question is what exactly should go inside method x()?

As an alternative I could provide a public def accessor to that private **val x** field. Like so:

```
trait ScalaTrait {

  self =>

  private val _x: Int = SomeVeryExpensiveOperation.do()
  def x = _x

}
```

But still, I'm now forced to implement that private **val _x** in my Java class, too, regardless of the private access modifier. How can I make this work and why must my Java class implement the **private val** field in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really want to do this. You're going to have to dive into the guts of how Scala implements mixins and reimplement it by hand in Java.

Here is a simple example, all in Scala:

```
trait X {
  val x = 5
}

class Y extends X
```

We can use `scalac -Xprint:mixin` to get an intermediate stage in the Scala compilation process that shows what Scala does to implement `Y`:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                     mixin]] // test20.scala
package <empty> {
  abstract trait X extends Object {
    <accessor> def X$_setter_$x_=(x$1: Int): Unit;
    <stable> <accessor> def x(): Int
  };
  class Y extends Object with X {
    <stable> <accessor> def x(): Int = Y.this.x;
    private[this] val x: Int = _;
    <accessor> def X$_setter_$x_=(x$1: Int): Unit = Y.this.x = x$1;
    def <init>(): Y = {
      Y.super.<init>();
      X$class./*X$class*/$init$(Y.this);
      ()
    }
  };
  abstract trait X$class extends  {
    def /*X$class*/$init$($this: X): Unit = {
      $this.X$_setter_$x_=(5);
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

All that stuff for `Y` you are going to have to implement by hand in Java. You need to define the field (`x`), the accessor method (also `x`), the setter method (`X$_setter_$x_`), and put the call to `X$class.$init$` in your constructor.

Comment: The initialiser is the real problem maker here, exposes a lot that you otherwise don't. And that's something that can't be fixed with the migration to a Java8 runtime.

Comment: I guess the safest approach is not to extend Scala traits from Java. Instead I let my Java code use the instantiated Scala class (I'm exposing the trait's features via delegation).